# limit number of ticks on a area chart using d3.scaleLog()

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a logarithmic scale for my areaCharts y-axis and 
limit the number of ticks on my y-axis using '.ticks()' but this isn't working as expected when i use d3.scale.Log().the code for this chart can be found below

```
var scale_y = d3.scale.log()
                   .base( 10 )
                   .domain([0.1, d3.max(data)])
                   .range([g_height, 0])

var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
                 .scale(scale_y)
                 .orient("left")
                 .ticks(5)
                 .tickFormat( d => d)
```

[image: Current image]

also providing the link here https://codepen.io/dsc1213/pen/pxVgrw. 
any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#log_ticks

> Note that the number of ticks cannot be customized (due to the nature of log scales);

`tickFormat()` is messing things up

It looks better with

```
var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale_y).orient("left");
```

As soon as I want to use `s` format display it shows numbers for every tick mark

---

**Edit**

If I use D3v5 I can get a better result.

[image: d3v5]

```
var y_axis = d3.axisLeft(scale_y).tickArguments([5,".0s"]);
```

```js
var svg_width = 500,
    svg_height = 250,
    margin = {left:50, right: 20, top:30, bottom:30},
    g_width = svg_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    g_height = svg_height - margin.top - margin.bottom

var data = [0.1, 30, 100, 300, 600, 1212]


var scale_x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, data.length-1]).range([0, g_width]),
    scale_y = d3.scaleLog().base( 10 ).domain([0.1, d3.max(data)]).range([g_height, 0])

var svg = d3.select("#container")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", svg_width)
.attr("height", svg_height)

var g = svg.append("svg:g")
.attr("width", g_width)
.attr("height", g_height)
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

var area = d3.area()
.x(function(d,i) { return scale_x(i); })
.y0(g_height)
.y1(function(d) { return scale_y(d); })
.curve(d3.curveCardinal)

g.append("svg:path")
.attr("d", area(data))
.style("fill", "steelblue");

var x_axis = d3.axisBottom(scale_x).ticks(5);
var y_axis = d3.axisLeft(scale_y).tickArguments([5,".0s"]);

g.append("svg:g")
.call(x_axis)
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + g_height + ")")

g.append("svg:g")
.call(y_axis)
.append("text")
.text("Price($)")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr("dy", "1em")
.attr("fill", "black")
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.domain, .tick line {
  stroke: gray;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<div id = "container"></div>
```

Comment: If i don't use tickFormat the ticks are returned in exponential format and also there are lines rendered on the y-axis

Comment: @dsc: I can get a better result with d3v5, see the edit

Comment: @dsc: I think this is a bug, `tickFormat` should only change how the tick text is displayed and not change the number of ticks.

Comment: In log mode, for me the only way to limit numbers of ticks is to use "tickArguments"